# How to filter by time range within a day instead of date range in Fabric/Crashlytics?

Tags: google-fabric

I am using Fabric/Crashlytics and I want to filter by *time* instead of *date*. As far as I see, the Fabric UI does not support this -- it is only possible to select "Last 60 minutes", "Last 24 hours", "Last 7 Days", ..., "Custom Range". And "custom range" is only for selecting a specific day (24 hours).

Since our project in production have a *lot* of logs, it is simply not sufficient for me to filter by the last 24 hours, since I'm trying to find a specific session and it's like finding a needle in a haystack. I need to filter more specifically, e.g. "from 08:00 GMT to 08:15 GMT".

I noticed that the Fabric URL (when filtering by device & OS) looks something like this:

```
https://fabric.io/x/android/apps/<myapp>/issues?time=1535500800000%3A1535587199999&event_type=all&subFilter=device&state=all&build%5B0%5D=1.0.0%20%284047%29&osMinorVersion%5B0%5D=4.4.4&deviceModel%5B0%5D=<some device>
```

Notice the `time` part: `time=1535500800000%3A1535587199999`, which in this case is translated to the entire day of August 29 in GMT+0 time. I tried narrowing down these timestamps by making my own Epoch timestamps and inserting them in the URL (example: `time=1535522100000%3A1535522400000`), but it looks like the Fabric website gives up and throws a bunch of JavaScript exceptions:

[image: Chrome logs]

**HOW** do I filter by a narrow time range in Fabric?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. We don't have a more fine grained time view that what is already available via the dashboard. I will share the desire for this internally.